# Why can't I sometimes spawn on teammates?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

When I die in game, I have the option to spawn either on my base, or on a teammate that is still alive.

But sometimes, nothing happens when I click on the teammate and then the button to join the round. My cooldown time is past 0 at the moment, so that should not be the problem.
While this happens, I also see, sometimes, that the teammate is a semi-transparent triangle on the map, somehow darker green. What would that indicate to?

Okay that's two questions now, but I still would like to learn the spawning mechanics on teammates. When can I spawn and when can I not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are a few examples of when you cant spawn on a team mate:

1. If your squad member is in a full vehicle
2. If your squad member is out of the combat area
3. Sometimes when your squad member is in complicated terrain (like jumping though piles of rocks) there is no space for you to spawn, in these situations the game will wait until there is space to avoid you getting stuck
4. You cant spawn on a squad member while they have their parachute deployed
5. Sometimes the game will auto-balance the teams, I have found this can happen midround while the player is still alive. If the player is still alive the game waits until their next death to move them, however in the mean time I have found myself unable to spawn on this player.

Im sure this isnt a complete list but its the ones i can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Do you know which ones are causing the triangle to appear semi-transparent?

Comment: @Bora - for sure #2, I think #3 too.

Comment: Yeah it definately happens with 2 and 3, another thing I can add is that if the person you are trying to spawn on is surrounded very closely by friendlies you will potentially experience the same problem as in #3

Comment: An obvious one is also when they are also dead and at the same screen, trying to respawn near you and wondering why then can't :)